# Check if a Binary Search Tree is valid

Tags: ruby, tree

I've written the following code in Ruby:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :left, :right

  def initialize(data=nil, left=nil, right=nil)
    @data  = data
    @left  = left
    @right = right
  end

  def valid?(min=nil, max=nil)
    if @left.nil? && @right.nil? 
      # base case (leaf node)
      return false if min && @data < min
      return false if max && @data >= max
      true # otherwise
    else
      return false if @left && !@left.valid?(min, @data)
      return false if @right && !@right.valid?(@data, max)
      true # otherwise
    end
  end
end
```

The basic idea is that when you *turn left* (i.e. recurse into left child), the children should be *less than* the value of the current node (i.e. you're setting a `max = @data` limit for the children).

To test it, I did:

```
root = 
  Node.new(10,
    Node.new(5,
      Node.new(2), Node.new(7)),
    Node.new(15,
      Node.new(8), Node.new(20)))

puts root.valid?.inspect # => false (because 8 isn't between 10 -> 15)
```

Seems to work for me, but would love any feedback (everything's fair game, including style, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having to pass - or even being able to pass - `min` and `max` to the method doesn't seem quite right. The arguments are only there for the method's own use when calling "itself" on its child nodes - they're not really part of the class's API. So that smells a bit.

I'd take a different approach, and add an `#each` method:

```
def each(&block)
  left.each(&block) unless left.nil?
  yield data
  right.each(&block) unless right.nil?
end
```

This lets you say `root.each { |n| ... }` like you would with an array. And it lets you include `Enumerable` - since all that requires is that your class implements an `#each` method - giving you a bunch of methods for free. For instance, you might implement `#valid?` like so:

```
def valid?
  each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| a <= b }
end
```

And of course, thanks to `Enumerable`, you can also do things like `root.to_a`, `root.reduce`, `root.include?` and other good stuff.

In all, you get this:

```
class Node
  include Enumerable

  attr_accessor :data, :left, :right

  def initialize(data = nil, left = nil, right = nil)
    @data = data
    @left = left
    @right = right
  end

  def each(&block)
    left.each(&block) unless left.nil?
    yield data
    right.each(&block) unless right.nil?
  end

  def valid?
    each_cons(2).all? { |a, b| a <= b }
  end
end
```

Beyond that, your current code looks good, only a few comments:

- Since you have `attr_accessor` synthesized methods, use them. Don't access instance variables directly with `@...` unless you have to. The point is, that if you need to customize access, you can simply swap out the synthesized accessor with a custom one, and no other code has to change, since it'll still be calling the method.
- But speaking of accessors, using `attr_accessor` can be a bit blunt for the `left` and `right` attributes, since it lets anyone, anywhere, set them to something nonsensical, like `root.left = "foobar!"`. That'll break things, since you suddenly have non-`Node` nodes in your tree. So I'd suggest using `attr_reader`s, but adding your own assignment methods, e.g. `def left=(node); ...; end`. That'll let you check things before assigning.
- The method in question might be named `#sorted?` instead. `valid?` could imply any number of things. *Edit: You may actually want to use `(a <=> b) <= 0`, as that's what used to sort objects, instead of just `a <= b`.*
- Don't bother aligning the `=` assignment operators like you do in the initializer. Yeah, it's pretty, and I'm often tempted to do the same, but it's a bit of busywork that - if you ever have to change the code - requires you to redo it. I've read through my own commit history on projects and wondered why seemingly unchanged lines showed up in the diff, only to realise I was messing around with the whitespace and confusing future-me.

You can also take a different tack, and use an `add`/`insert`/`<<` or something method to add data to the tree, rather than requiring someone else to create new `Node`s. E.g `root << 15` would traverse the tree, and find the right place to insert the value, creating a new node to hold it, etc. etc.. That way, you won't really need a `valid?` method.

Comment: @kyrill Good point. But why the attitude? Also, fixed

Comment: Excellent feedback; `each_cons` is new to me, so I learned that ... in addition to reading up on `Enumerable` which I hadn't extended before. Thanks a lot!